# Javascript else if statement not working for bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Hello everyone I'm working on creating conditional statements for my bootstrap modal but I notice that else if condition doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
<!--Awaiting Verification Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="awaitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-5" align="center">
         <h3>Awaiting Profile Verification and Confirmation.</h3>
         <h5>Check your email for more details</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Verify Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="verifyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="verifyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-5" align="center">
         <h3>Your withdrawal Verification has been confirmed.</h3>
         <button class="btn btn-success">Proceed</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
   $(window).on('load', function() {
     
  if({{awaitingapproval() == 1}}) {
  $('#awaitModal').modal('show');
}
 else if({{awaitingapproval() == 2}}) {
     $('#verifyModal').modal('show');
 }
 else {
  $('#awaitModal').modal('hide');
  $('#verifyModal').modal('hide');
 }
});

</script>
```

When I comment out else if the if condition modal shows but when the else if is there it doesn't show in fact no modal shows. Please someone help me out.

Comment: Why the {{}} ? `if({{awaitingapproval() == 1}}) {` If that is templating why do you even have ifs?  You can wrap the tests on the server - please tag your templating if used

Comment: `{{awaitingapproval() == 1}}` doesn't look right. What are you trying to do here? Did you mean to use `(awaitingapproval() == 1)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement was incorrect. I changed the code a bit and it works fine now! You can try it out. I generate a random number between 1 and 4 and put that in the variable `awaitingapproval` as you can see below, if its 1 or 2 the correct modal will show. Just hit run code snippet to get 1 or 2 or you can change the value.

```js
   $(window).on('load', function() {
    const awaitingapproval = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1) + 1)
    const awaitingapprovalNumber = document.querySelector('#awaitingapprovalNumber')
    awaitingapprovalNumber.innerHTML = awaitingapproval
    
    if (awaitingapproval === 1) {
      $('#awaitModal').modal('show');
      return; // Show await modal and then stop the code
    }
     
    if (awaitingapproval === 2) {
       $('#verifyModal').modal('show');
       return; // Show verify modal and then stop the code
    }

    // If awaitingapproval is not 1 or 2 then hide all modals
    $('#awaitModal').modal('hide');
    $('#verifyModal').modal('hide');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p id="awaitingapprovalNumber"></p>
<div class="modal fade" id="awaitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-5" align="center">
         <h3>Awaiting Profile Verification and Confirmation.</h3>
         <h5>Check your email for more details</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--Verify Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="verifyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="verifyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-5" align="center">
         <h3>Your withdrawal Verification has been confirmed.</h3>
         <button class="btn btn-success">Proceed</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```